# ZeroDivisionError: division by zero in chess.py

Tags: python, pygame, chess

I have created an chess seeing video and when it completes i got an error

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

my whole code: https://onlinegdb.com/HJR_9t2nD

```py
board = [ ['Rb', 'Nb', 'Bb', 'Qb', 'Kb', 'Bb', 'Nb', 'Rb'], #8
          ['Pb', 'Pb', 'Pb', 'Pb', 'Pb', 'Pb', 'Pb', 'Pb'], #7
          [  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],  #6
          [  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],  #5
          [  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],  #4
          [  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],  #3
          ['Pw', 'Pw', 'Pw',  'Pw', 'Pw', 'Pw', 'Pw', 'Pw'], #2
          ['Rw', 'Nw', 'Bw',  'Qw', 'Kw', 'Bw', 'Nw', 'Rw'] ]#1
          # a      b     c     d     e     f     g     h
```

```py
def isOccupiedby(board,x,y,color):
    if board[x / y]==0:
        #the square has nothing on it.
        return False
```

Here's full error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "chess.py", line 1054, in negamax
    moves = allMoves(position, colorsign)
  File "chess.py", line 842, in allMoves
    listofpieces = getallpieces(position,color)
  File "chess.py", line 831, in getallpieces
    if isOccupiedby(board,i,j,color):
  File "chess.py", line 458, in isOccupiedby
    if board[x / y]==0:
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chess.py", line 1713, in <module>
    createShades([])
  File "chess.py", line 955, in createShades
    if isCheck(position,'white'):
  File "chess.py", line 801, in isCheck
    return isAttackedby(position,x,y,enemy)
  File "chess.py", line 496, in isAttackedby
    findPossibleSquares(position,x,y,True)) #The true argument
  File "chess.py", line 569, in findPossibleSquares
    if isOccupiedby(board,kx,y,enemy_color):
  File "chess.py", line 458, in isOccupiedby
    if board[x / y]==0:
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: are x and y chess board coordinates?

Comment: @Rabbid I said function arguments not the complete code

Answer (score 0):

`/` is the division operator. If the divisor is zero, you will get an exception.

Very likely you tried to access an element of the grid. If `board` is a list of lists, you must use the subscription operator twice in a row. Since the grid is organized in rows, the first subscription index is `y` and the second is `x`:

<s>`if board[x / y]==0:`</s>

```py
if board[y][x]==0:
```